# File.Open Cross Thread Writing

Tags: c#, stream, binaryformatter

Is it safe to open a file and write a stream to it across multiple threads? If no what could I implement to make it safe?

Comment: Are you sharing the same stream object, or trying to open a different stream in each thread?

Comment: To save your sanity, just don't do it. Marshal all your writes to a queue structure that is handled by a single thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the standard FileStream is not thread-safe.

You should use `var safe = Stream.Synchronized(File.Open(...));` to create a thread-safe wrapper.

[`Stream.Synchronized()` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.synchronized.aspx)

Comment: Are there any examples available of this implementation, I have been searching Google but it did not prove to be fruitful..

Comment: you just create the wrapper using `Stream.Synchronized` and then use it like you would use any other stream. Pass it to another method, create a StreamReader/Writer on it etc.

Comment: Thanks! One last question, does it preserve the order of what I'm writting? If no how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

No.  This is not thread safe.  Intuitively, how does one write to a file when the index is a moving target? One idea is to create separate files and combine them with another process, possibly triggered by a completed event of some kind (e.g. all files arrived).

The concept of writing to a single file with multiple threads has some code smell. IMO, re-examine your options and come up with a different way of approaching this problem.

Comment: I could see maybe doing this in a quick and simple logging function of some sort, but that's a very good point that writing to an open file handle with multiple threads may indicate a poor design pattern.  In the case of a log writer, a queue is probably a better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

No; it isn't safe by itself, but you can use the `lock` keyword to control cross-thread access to the FileStream object.

For instance:

```
FileStream fStream = File.Open('foo.txt', FileMode.Append);

lock (fStream)
{
  // Some operation on fStream
}
```

The answer posted by Knaģis may be the way to go in this instance, but mutex locking with the `lock` keyword is a more general solution.